# What is the difference between these two headers?

Tags: c++, header-files

I have these two header files and one produces an error if I don't put `std::` in front of all string declarations and the other doesn't. I was just wondering what the difference between the two was.

The following will produce an error if the `std::` is not in front of the string declarations:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#pragma once

#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H

struct Item
{
    public:
        std::string object;

        int numOfColors;
        std::string colors;

        int sizeSmall;
        int sizeLarge;
};

class database
{
private:
    void fillDatabase(std::vector<Item>);
public:
    void getDatabase(std::vector<Item>);
};

#endif
```

The following code will not produce an error:

```
#include <string>

#pragma once

#ifndef GUISTRUCT_H
#define GUISTRUCT_H

struct guiValues
{
    public:
        string shape;
        string color;
        int width;
        double squareProbability;
        double rectangleProbability;
        double circleProbability;

        string firstMostLikelyObject;
        double FMLOprobability;
        string secondMostLikelyObject;
        double SMLOprobability;
        string thirdMostLikelyObject;
        double TMLOprobability;

};

#endif
```

Comment: The difference between the two code snippets that you have in your question is that the second code snippet should not compile. I get "C4430: missing type specifier" errors on Visual C++ for all instances of `string` in your second code snippet. What else are you including? What compiler are you using?

Comment: You must be including some other headers as well. Just guessing that on of those contains a `using namespace std`.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. Whatever is built into Visual Studio 2010. Is there a way to check that?

Comment: You're most likely using Visual C++, so it can't be a compiler bug since I'm getting `C4430` errors for the second code snippet. Is there a `using namespace std` or `using std::string` in any of your header files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second file is included after some other that defines

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: The OP's problem is exactly why experienced C++ programmers don't recommend putting `using namespace std;` in header files!

Comment: +1 whoever wrote that should be given the honor of removing all such declarations from the repo and fixing the builds in the process.

Comment: That was it! After looking through several header files I found it. I commented it out to test it, and sure enough my second piece of code will now not compile without the std::. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`string` is declared in the `namespace std`. So one needs to use the namespace std to make use of string.  it can be done in two ways:

By explicitly mentioning which type(string in this case) you want to include from the std namespace as in case 1, `std::string colors`
OR
By enabling the entire std namespace, `using namespace std;` which imports all types from the namespace in your global namespace.(Please note that Doing this in headers is not recommended)

In the second case seems you have included the entire std namespace before the particular include and hence it is not giving an error even without exlpicit mention of `std::String`